# How to set up custom query filter for Elementor to display a message if there are no posts for query but display the posts if there are any

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I wanted to create a custom filter query to list all draft posts and be able to display a message that there are no draft posts, if there are none.

I created a loop grid in elementor that lists draft posts but I want a situation where it will display a custom message when there are no posts. Please see below my sample code which does not work. It simply does not run.

```
function custom_query_filter_show_draft_posts_for_current_user( $query ) {
    // Get the current user's ID
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Set the query to show draft posts authored by the current user
    $query->set('author', $current_user_id);
    $query->set('post_status', 'draft');

    // Check if the query has any draft posts
    $query_result = new WP_Query($query);
    if (!$query_result->have_posts()) {
        echo "You don't have any draft posts.";
    }

    // Restore global post data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/drafted', 'custom_query_filter_show_draft_posts_for_current_user' );
```

Would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Elementor has a special hook `elementor/query/query_results` which you can use to display some text when a query does not return any results, like this:

```
add_action('elementor/query/query_results', function($query) {
    $total = $query->found_posts;
    if ($total == 0) {
        echo '<h1 style="text-align:center;">No results found. </h1>';
    }
});
```

Source and more info: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/7624#issuecomment-635468969)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I added an ID to my loop grid element and placed the following code snippet in an HTML element directly below it with the following code

```
<div id="message"></div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Check if the element with the ID "events" does not exist
    if ($('#events').length == 0) {
        // If the element exists, output the text
        $('#message').text('No posts found.');
    }
});
</script>
```

Replace #events in the code with the id of your loop grid element.

This snippet will output the text "No posts found." if the id #events is not found.

Hopefully, Elementor add this feature in the future.